# creating a window in c++ using Winbgim

Tags: c++, window, resolution, monitor, bgi

I want to creat a fullscreen window in the primary monitor. I have done but the window begin at the coordinate 3x0 instead 0x0. what should I do to correct my code?

here is my code:

```
 #include <graphics.h>

 int main()
 {
 int hor=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
 int ver=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
 initwindow(hor, ver, "Convex Hull", 0, 0);
 getch();
 closegraph();
 return( 0 );
 }
```

P.S. I use the WinBGIm Graphics Library with the CodeBlocks-EP IDE environment

thanks in advance

Comment: How do you determine the actual placement of the window?

Comment: I think that the point (leftmost,topmost) of the screen corresponds the point (0,0)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that framework, but if it gives you access to the Windows API level "window handle", then you can use that call API functions such as MoveWindow and SetWindowPos (as I recall the latter is more powerful, but check them out).

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the function:

```
int initwindow(int width, int height, const char* title="Windows BGI", int left=0, int top=0)
```

All you have to do is set top and left so it would fit your screen, in my case it's like that:

```
initwindow(1920,1009, "Window",-8,-1);
```